# Republic Logo In Revenge Of The Sith

Tags: star-wars

In Revenge of The Sith, what is that symbol with the two half circles inside a yellow circle called. I can't find it anywhere online, please help!

Comment: An image of the symbol you are looking to identify might help.

Comment: Or a timestamp of where you see it in the film

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're referring to the symbol that denotes a ship of the Republic Navy's [**Open Circle Fleet**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Circle_Fleet)

[image]

> *The Open Circle Fleet was a fleet in the Galactic Republic Navy. During the Clone Wars, the fleet fought against the Separatist navy in the Battle of Coruscant.*
>
> [image]